# go - How to mock fiber context

Tags: go, testing, mocking, go-fiber

I've been trying to mock a fiber.Ctx but I have not been able to make it work I have been getting this error:

> --- FAIL: TestCheckHeaders (0.00s)
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
> [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x12085f0]

The code that I am trying to test:

**CheckHeaders.go**

```golang
 package middleware

 import "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"

 func CheckHeaders(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    headers := c.GetReqHeaders()
    if headers["headerValue"] == "true"{
        return c.Next()
    } else {
        return c.SendStatus(401)

    }
 }
```

**CheckHeaders_test.go**

```golang
 package middleware

 import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
 )

 func TestCheckHeaders(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        c *fiber.Ctx
    }
    fiberContext := fiber.Ctx{}

    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {name: "test 1",
            args:    args{c: &fiberContext},
            wantErr: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if err := CheckHeaders(tt.args.c); (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("CheckHeaders() error = %v, wantErr %v", err,tt.wantErr)
            }
        })
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

This was how I set up a new context that I could manipulate for testing. Hope it helps.

```
app := fiber.New()
c := app.AcquireCtx(&fasthttp.RequestCtx{})
```

`c` will be a fresh `*fiber.Ctx`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own interface with methods you need to use from `fiber.Ctx` struct and make mock for the interface.

After that you are going to handle `fiber.Ctx` as implementation of for example `Ctxer` interface so you will be able to mock it using https://github.com/golang/mock and use the mock in your tests.

It's gonna look like this

```
type Ctxer interface {
    GetReqHeaders() map[string]string
    Next() (err error)
    SendStatus(status int) error
}

func CheckHeaders(c Ctxer) error {
    headers := c.GetReqHeaders()
    if headers["headerValue"] == "true" {
        return c.Next()
    } else {
        return c.SendStatus(401)
    }
}
```